# The tikz-cd package is over running the bottom margin is a particular class file

Tags: margins, document-classes, tikz-cd

I am using a particular class file [`fundam.cls`](http://fi.mimuw.edu.pl/fundam.zip). However, when I add the tikz-cd package, the bottom margin overruns. I suspect it is because the tikz-cd package is changing the paper type, making it smaller.

Here is a minimal working example for the bad behavior:

```
\documentclass{fundam}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1001}
\issue{XXI~(2001)}

\title{How to Prepare Articles for Fundamenta Informaticae}

\address{Address for correspondence goes here}

\author{First Author\thanks{Thanks for something to somebody}\\
Institute of Informatics \\
Warsaw University\\ Banacha 2, 02-097 Warszawa, Poland\\
first{@}mimuw.edu.pl
\and Second Author\thanks{Thanks for something else to somebody else}\\
Department of Informatics \\
City University \\
London, England } \maketitle

\runninghead{F. Author, S. Author}{How to Prepare Articles for FI}

\begin{abstract}
  This guide is for authors who are preparing papers for
  \emph{Fundamenta Informaticae\/} using the \LaTeXe\ document
  preparation system and the \texttt{fundam.cls} class file.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
\LaTeXe, document class file, Bib\TeX
\end{keywords}


\section{Introduction}

The \emph{Fundamenta Informaticae\/} class file is based on the
standard \LaTeXe\ \texttt{article} class as described in the \LaTeX\
manual.  It means that the paper prepared to be process with the
standard \texttt{article} class can be processed with the
\texttt{fundam} class without any modifications.  Commands which
differ from the standard \LaTeX\ interface, or which are provided in
addition to the standard interface, are explained in this guide. This
guide is not a substitute for the \LaTeX\ manual itself.

The \texttt{fundam} class can be used only with \LaTeXe. It is not
supposed to work with the obsolete 2.09 (or earlier) version of
\LaTeX.


\end{document}
```

Without the tikz-cd package, it runs perfectly.

Comment: You can reduce your MWE to `\documentclass{fundam}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
hallo
\end{document}`

Comment: It's not `tikz-cd` *per se*: the same happens with `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Using showframe, and not tikzcd, shows that the diagram of the page layout itself overruns the bottom margin.

Comment: @egreg yes!
I think the fundam class file itself has bad page layout, but no idea why it does work perfectly without tikz/tikzcd/showframe.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't see this problem with your code. Same result with and without `tikz-cd`, which is just a wrapper for a tikz library.

Comment: @Bernard No bottom margin problem when using tikz? How come, I have cross-checked it in the sample tex file (present in the http://fi.mimuw.edu.pl/fundam.zip), still no success.

Comment: I didn't say when *using* tikz; I meant when *loading* it, as your question seems to say a mere loading results in a bottom margin problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just experienced the same problem with the `graphicx` package in the `fundam` class. I tried the solution provided by @egreg, but unfortunately, this didn't worked out for me.

I had a closer look at the *fundam.cls file* and looked up for the `\paperlength` and `\paperwidth` values.
There I found that the `\topmargin -2cm` on *line 115* was commented.
Removing the comment solved the problem for me.

```
            % $Id: fundam.cls,v 1.2 2000/06/24 06:57:31 piotrek Exp $
            % This file fuin.cls defines LaTeX 2e document class
            % for Fundamenta Informaticae.
            %Last modified 25/06/2016 by Marcin Szczuka
            % To be used with LaTeX 2e.
            %


            \newif\iffour\fourfalse
            \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
            \ProvidesClass{fundam}[1998/08/19 v1.1
             Fundamenta Informaticae document class]
            \DeclareOption{manyauthors}{\fourtrue}
            \DeclareOption{draft}{\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{article}}
            \DeclareOption{times}{\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{times}}}
            \DeclareOption{cmtt}{\AtEndOfClass{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}}}
            \DeclareOption{theoremsf}{\def\THstyle{\theorembodyfont{\sffamily}
                \theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\sffamily}}
              \def\PRstyle{\sffamily}}
            \DeclareOption{theoremnormal}{\def\THstyle{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}}
              \def\PRstyle{\relax}}
            \ExecuteOptions{final,theoremnormal,times,cmtt}
            \ProcessOptions
            \relax
            \LoadClass[11pt,twoside,onecolumn]{article}
            \RequirePackage{theorem}
            \RequirePackage{amsmath}
            %=======================================================================
            \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad} %% PU - 19 VIII
                                                  %% zmiana \enspace na \quad
            %=======================================================================
            %\def\ii{\footnotesize\em}
            %=======================================================================
            \def\issue#1{\gdef\@issue{#1}}
            \issue{XX~(\number\year)}  % zmiana (PU)
            \def\papernumber#1{\gdef\@papernumber{#1}}
            \papernumber{0000}
            \def\runninghead#1#2{\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}\gdef\@shorttitle{#2}}
            \runninghead{author}{short title}
            % this ugly thing for backwards compatibility:
            \let\markboth\runninghead
            %%%\setcounter{page}{163}

            \AtEndDocument{\label{::last page of FI article:\jobname::}}

            \def\@maketitle{\newpage%
                \renewcommand\thefootnote{\ifnum\c@footnote=7\relax C\else\@fnsymbol\c@footnote\fi}%
                \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
                \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 0em\noindent
                        {%
                            \@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark }}##1}%
              {\noindent\footnotesize\textit{Fundamenta Informaticae
                  \ignorespaces\@issue\unskip\space
                  \thepage--\pageref{::last page of FI article:\jobname::}}% zmiana - na -- (PU)
                  \hfill \thepage}
               \vskip .01em
              {\noindent\footnotesize\textit{DOI 10.3233/FI-2016-\@papernumber}}
              \vskip .01em
              {\noindent\footnotesize\textit{IOS Press}}
              \vskip 1.6em
              \par\hangindent=30pt\hangafter=0
              \pretolerance=10000
              \begin{flushleft}%
                {\Large\bfseries \@title\par}
                \vskip 1.7em
                {\normalsize\fontsize{10}{\f@baselineskip}\itshape
                  \tabcolsep=0pt
                  \lineskip0pt %??
            \iffour\@fourauthors\else
                  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
                    \reset@font\normalsize\bfseries\@author\relax
                  \end{tabular}\par\fi}%
                \nointerlineskip
              \end{flushleft}%
              \vskip .2em
              \footnoterule
              \vskip 3cm
              }

            \def\and{\\[5pt]\reset@font\normalsize\bfseries}

            \def\abstract{%
            \list{}{\advance\topsep by0.35cm\relax\small\rm
             \leftmargin=1cm
             \labelwidth\listparindent
             \itemindent\listparindent
             \rightmargin\leftmargin}\item[\hskip\labelsep\bf\abstractname.]}
            \let\endabstract=\endlist

            \def\keywords{%
            \list{}{\advance\topsep by0.35cm\relax\small\rm
             \leftmargin=1cm
             \labelwidth=\z@
             \listparindent=\z@
             \itemindent\listparindent
             \rightmargin\leftmargin}\item[\hskip\labelsep\bf Keywords: ]}
            \let\endkeywords=\endlist
            %=======================================================================
            \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
            \def\ps@fuin{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
              \def\@oddhead{\footnotesize\phantom{\thepage}%
                \hfil\textit{\@shortauthor\,/\,\@shorttitle}\hfil
                \thepage}
              \def\@oddfoot{}
              \def\@evenhead{\footnotesize\thepage
                \hfil \textit{\@shortauthor\,/\,\@shorttitle}\hfil
                \phantom{\thepage}}
              \def\@evenfoot{}
              }
            \pagestyle{fuin}
            \paperwidth 19.2cm
            \paperheight 26.2cm
            \textwidth 15.6cm
            \textheight 21.6cm
            %\topmargin -2cm  %Remove comment if you are using graphicx package
            \oddsidemargin 0.0cm
            \evensidemargin 0.0cm

            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % Theorem like environments

            \gdef\th@plain{\normalfont\itshape
              \def\@begintheorem##1##2{%
                    \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2.]}%

            \def\@opargbegintheorem##1##2##3{%
              \item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip \labelsep \theorem@headerfont
                                 ##1\ ##2.\ (##3)}%
                                \hbox{\strut}}}]}}
            %\def\@opargbegintheorem##1##2##3{%
            %   \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2.\ (##3)]\hfill\newline}}

            \theoremstyle{plain}
            \THstyle
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
            \newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}%[section]
            \newtheorem{fact}[definition]{Fact}%[section]
            \newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
            \newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
            \newtheorem{assumption}[definition]{Assumption}
            \newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
            \newtheorem{remark}[definition]{Remark}
            \newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
            \newtheorem{claim}[definition]{Claim}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

            %%\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{fact}{Fact}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
            %%\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[section]
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \newenvironment{proof}
              {\trivlist\PRstyle\item[]{\bfseries Proof:}\newline}{\QED\endtrivlist}
            \def\squareforqed{\hbox{\rlap{$\sqcap$}$\sqcup$}}
            \def\QED{\ifmmode\squareforqed\else{\unskip\nobreak\hfil
            \penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\squareforqed
            \parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}\fi}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

            \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
            \setlength\tabcolsep{9\p@}
            \setlength\belowcaptionskip{5\p@}

            \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
              \small
              \vskip\abovecaptionskip
              \sbox\@tempboxa{#1.\quad #2}%
              \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
                #1.\quad #2\par
              \else
                \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
              \fi
              \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

            \abovedisplayskip=7pt plus 2pt minus 5pt
            \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 2pt
            \belowdisplayskip=7pt plus 2pt minus 5pt
            \belowdisplayshortskip=5pt plus 2pt minus 3pt

            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \newcounter{ttmp}\setcounter{ttmp}{0}

            \def\QQQ{
            \setcounter{ttmp}{\thetmp}
            \setlength\maxl{0pt}
            \setbox0=\vbox{\def\corresponding{\relax}\def\thanks##1{\relax}%
              \csname @author\thettmp\endcsname}
            \setlength\tmpl{\ht0}\addtolength\tmpl{\dp0}
            \ifnum\tmpl>\maxl\relax\setlength\maxl{\tmpl}\fi
            \stepcounter{ttmp}
            \setbox0=\vbox{\def\corresponding{\relax}\def\thanks##1{\relax}%
              \csname @author\thettmp\endcsname}
            \setlength\tmpl{\ht0}\addtolength\tmpl{\dp0}
            \ifnum\tmpl>\maxl\relax\setlength\maxl{\tmpl}\fi
            %\message{\the\maxl}
            \addtolength\maxl{0.8\baselineskip}
            %
            \halign{##&##\cr
            \hbox{\global\stepcounter{tmp}
            \vbox to \maxl{\hsize=0.5\hsize\upshape\bfseries\csname @author\thetmp\endcsname\vfill}}&
            \hbox{\global\stepcounter{tmp}
            \vbox to \maxl{\hsize=0.5\hsize\upshape\bfseries\csname @author\thetmp\endcsname\vfill}}\cr}
            }

            \def\END{\relax}
            \def\AUTORZY#1{\doAUTOR#1\and\END
            \setcounter{tmp}{0}
            \let\ORIGBS=\\
            \def\\{\fontsize{10}{\f@baselineskip}\mdseries\itshape\ORIGBS}
            \vbox{\loop
            \QQQ
            \ifnum\thetmp<\theauthor
            \repeat}\par}
            \def\doAUTOR#1\and#2{\formatauthor{#1}%\message{^^J}
            \if#2\relax%\message{KONIEC^^J}
            \let\next\relax\else\let\next\doAUTOR\fi\next#2}

            \def\@fourauthors{\expandafter\expandafter\AUTORZY{\@author}}

            \newcounter{author}\setcounter{author}{0}
            \newcounter{tmp}\setcounter{tmp}{0}

            \newlength\maxl
            \newlength\tmpl

            \def\formatauthor#1{\stepcounter{author}%\message{****\theauthor}
              \expandafter\def\csname @author\theauthor\endcsname{#1}
            \setcounter{tmp}{\theauthor}\stepcounter{tmp}
              \expandafter\def\csname @author\thetmp\endcsname{\relax}
            %\message{^^J<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<^^J}
            %\expandafter\show\csname @author\theauthor\endcsname
            %\message{^^J>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>^^J}
            }

            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

            \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
                \parindent 0em%
                \noindent
                {\@makefnmark }#1}
            \def\@makefnmark{{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%

            \def\acknowledgements{\section*{Acknowledgements}}

            \def\corresponding{\advance\c@footnote by -1\global\renewcommand\thefootnote{C}
                \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 0em\noindent
                        {%
                            \@textsuperscript{C}}##1}%
            \footnotemark
            \protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
              \protect\footnotetext[7]{Corresponding author}}%
            }

            \def\address#1{{\renewcommand\thefootnote{\relax}%
            \footnotetext{Address for correspondence: #1}}}
            \def\thanksas#1{\@textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol#1}}


            \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
                 {\section*{\refname
                    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
                  \small
                  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
                       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
                        \leftmargin\labelwidth
                        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
                        \@openbib@code
                        \usecounter{enumiv}%
                        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
                        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
                  \sloppy
                  \clubpenalty4000
                  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
                  \widowpenalty4000%
                  \sfcode`\.\@m}
                 {\def\@noitemerr
                   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
                  \endlist}

            \gdef\@ltag{\relax}
            \def\ltag#1{\gdef\@ltag{$#1$}}

            \def\mkltag{\if\@ltag\relax\else\llap{\hbox to \hsize{\@ltag\hss}}\fi\gdef\@ltag{\relax}}

            %\def\endequation{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnnum\mkltag}$$\@ignoretrue}

            \def\@@eqncr{\let\reserved@a\relax
                \ifcase\@eqcnt \def\reserved@a{& & &}\or \def\reserved@a{& &}%
                 \or \def\reserved@a{&}\else
                   \let\reserved@a\@empty
                   \@latex@error{Too many columns in eqnarray environment}\@ehc\fi
                 \reserved@a \if@eqnsw\@eqnnum\mkltag\stepcounter{equation}\fi
                 \global\@eqnswtrue\global\@eqcnt\z@\cr}


            \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\mkltag}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem permanently. After lot of hit and trials, I went for xy-pic package for the commutative diagrams and figures.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually *no* problem; it's just how recent versions of the software deal with output page dimensions.

The `fundam` class is from 1998 and its pagination parameters are set so that the text block appears (almost) centered on A4 paper.

However, recent versions of LaTeX try to better cope with the problem, so they *do* set the paper width and height based on the value of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`. This happens as soon as you load `graphicx` (which TikZ does).

The remedy is simple: before `\begin{document}` reset the paper parameters to A4.

```
\documentclass{fundam}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% everything has been set; reset the page dimensions to A4
\setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1001}
\issue{XXI~(2001)}

\title{How to Prepare Articles for Fundamenta Informaticae}

\address{Address for correspondence goes here}

\author{First Author\thanks{Thanks for something to somebody}\\
Institute of Informatics \\
Warsaw University\\ Banacha 2, 02-097 Warszawa, Poland\\
first{@}mimuw.edu.pl
\and Second Author\thanks{Thanks for something else to somebody else}\\
Department of Informatics \\
City University \\
London, England } \maketitle

\runninghead{F. Author, S. Author}{How to Prepare Articles for FI}

\begin{abstract}
  This guide is for authors who are preparing papers for
  \emph{Fundamenta Informaticae\/} using the \LaTeXe\ document
  preparation system and the \texttt{fundam.cls} class file.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
\LaTeXe, document class file, Bib\TeX
\end{keywords}


\section{Introduction}

The \emph{Fundamenta Informaticae\/} class file is based on the
standard \LaTeXe\ \texttt{article} class as described in the \LaTeX\
manual.  It means that the paper prepared to be process with the
standard \texttt{article} class can be processed with the
\texttt{fundam} class without any modifications.  Commands which
differ from the standard \LaTeX\ interface, or which are provided in
addition to the standard interface, are explained in this guide. This
guide is not a substitute for the \LaTeX\ manual itself.

The \texttt{fundam} class can be used only with \LaTeXe. It is not
supposed to work with the obsolete 2.09 (or earlier) version of
\LaTeX.

The \emph{Fundamenta Informaticae\/} class file is based on the
standard \LaTeXe\ \texttt{article} class as described in the \LaTeX\
manual.  It means that the paper prepared to be process with the
standard \texttt{article} class can be processed with the
\texttt{fundam} class without any modifications.  Commands which
differ from the standard \LaTeX\ interface, or which are provided in
addition to the standard interface, are explained in this guide. This
guide is not a substitute for the \LaTeX\ manual itself.

The \texttt{fundam} class can be used only with \LaTeXe. It is not
supposed to work with the obsolete 2.09 (or earlier) version of
\LaTeX.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't this render the `fundram` class obsolete?

Comment: @Alenanno For certain they should fix it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the detailing, I have mailed the problem to the concerned people.
One more side-query, Is there any other package which draws simple commutative diagrams without using graphicx, so that the margin remains unaffected?

Comment: @AnujMore You may try Xy-pic: `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`. It's not as straightforward as `tikz-cd`. On the other hand, if you happen to load `graphicx` for including a file, the problem will reappear.